# Print Array in HighChart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am facing a problem printing an array into HighCharts.

```
var FirstTurnOver =new Array();
```

This array Contains 100,345,212,444,121,111,65 all values are dynamically fetching from the server.
Now I have to show them in series.

```
series: [{
    data: FirstTurnOver  
}]
```

This doesn't print anything on my Y axis.

Comment: How your FirstTurnOver array looks like?

Comment: 100,345,212,444,121,111,65

Comment: Is an array or string ?Recreate it as live demo

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/376a3k14/1/

Comment: Outside the for loop I am able to print FirstTurnOver array in this form
100,345,212,444,121,111,65

Comment: But I need a example which visuatlise entire data, because in your example, yo are referring to localstorage which is empty in my case. So is any chance to replicate it as working demo ?

Comment: RecordDetails Demand Deposits|100|123|30/09/2014~30/10/2014#Term Deposits|345|234|30/09/2014~30/10/2014#Demand Loans|212|222|30/09/2014~30/10/2014#Term Loans|444|221|30/09/2014~30/10/2014#Cash in Hand|121|211|30/09/2014~30/10/2014#PNL|111|445|30/09/2014~30/10/2014#CD Ratio|65|63|

Comment: Its difficult to show you a demo but i have shown you what my localStorage contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array contains numbers of strings, you just need to convert strings to numbers

```
FirstTurnOver.map(function (el) { return +el  })
// The same but a little shorter
// FirstTurnOver.map(Number) 
// or before push 
// FirstTurnOver.push(+billerdetails1);
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/376a3k14/3/)